# Movement of data in a horizontal oriented listbox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, listbox

I have a wpf listbox and two buttons(up and down).

If the user selects the any item in the list and clicks on down button,all the following items(including the selected item) must shift downwards. And similarly, on click of up button, it should move up.

Example has been explained below :-

```
                   Student 1     Student 2     Student 3
       Sem            1             1             1
       Physics       68            87            70
       Chemistry     78            89            78
       Math          62            77            80
       Sem           2             2             2
       Physics       78            69            78
       Chemistry     58            79            88
       Math          72            67            90
```

In the above table, if the user selects first semester item for student 2 and clicks on down button, the data for student 2 should move down as shown below :-

```
                   Student 1     Student 2     Student 3
       Sem           1                           1
       Physics       68                          70
       Chemistry     78                          78
       Math          62                          80
       Sem           2             1             2
       Physics       78            87            78
       Chemistry     58            89            88
       Math          72            77            90
```

The data which got shifted should be retrievable.
I am using observable collection to bind the itemsource of listbox. 
Below is my sample code:-

```
<Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="myTemplate">
            <StackPanel>
                <Label Background="Purple" Foreground="White" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="4">
                    <Label.Content>
                        <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <TextBlock>Student Name:</TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </WrapPanel>
                    </Label.Content>
                </Label>
                <WrapPanel>
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding LstSubjects}" BorderThickness="0" >
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <WrapPanel Grid.Row="0">
                                        <TextBlock> Sem:</TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Semester}"></TextBlock>
                                    </WrapPanel>
                                    <WrapPanel Grid.Row="1">
                                        <TextBlock> Physics:</TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Physics}"></TextBlock>
                                    </WrapPanel>
                                    <WrapPanel  Grid.Row="2">
                                        <TextBlock> Chemistry:</TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Chemistry}"></TextBlock>
                                    </WrapPanel>
                                    <WrapPanel  Grid.Row="3">
                                        <TextBlock> Maths:</TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Maths}"></TextBlock>
                                    </WrapPanel>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </WrapPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

              <Grid>
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding StudentModel}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myTemplate}" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    </ListBox>
                </Grid>
```

Please note that the listbox contains student name and list of all subject marks(Sem,Physics,Chemistry,Maths).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you want to manage item-bundles of "Sem/Physics/Chemistry/Math". You could create an itemtemplate for that and arrange that in each row. Moving data up down is very unusual. Basically I guess that your table arrangement is improvable.

Comment: @deafjeff : Thanks for your answer. You are right, I need to manage several item bundles for each student. Could you please share some sapmle code because I am really stuck on this use case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample giving you 2 approaches, showing common ways of handling your data in wpf. This is not an answer to your original question.
From your comment, it seems you want to go another direction, so I post this as an answer. Feeld free to redefine your intention and I will edit this post.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MyViewmodel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<StackPanel>
    <!-- let Datagrid create the columns -->
    <DataGrid Name="MyDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Students}">
    </DataGrid>

    <!-- A listview with itemtemplate grouping the proprties -->
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Students}">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Semester}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Physics}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Chemistry}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Math}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

.. and the cs code:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Semester { get; set; }
    public int Physics { get; set; }
    public int Chemistry { get; set; }
    public int Math { get; set; }
};

public class MyViewmodel
{
    public MyViewmodel()
    {
        Students = new ObservableCollection<Student>
        {   
            new Student { Name="John", Semester = 1, Physics = 50, Chemistry = 60, Math = 70 },
            new Student { Name="Tim", Semester = 2, Physics = 80, Chemistry = 50, Math = 70 },
            new Student { Name="Aaron", Semester = 3, Physics = 40, Chemistry = 90, Math = 70 }
        };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
};

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }       
}
}
```

[image: ..the vs designer output:]

Comment: Thanks @deafjeff. Your code does solve the problem of showing data in the required way. Using listview or listbox rather than datagrid is a better idea. I have achieved the same using Listbox.I added another listbox in the itemtemplate of the first listbox which groups the marks for each semester. However, I am still working on the movement of data.

Comment: So as you didn't change text but the code, I guess you still want to move Items vertically, which is a bit unusual. As I understood: When you click "down", the underlying row gets the block from above. So in the click-handler, you need to shift the data inside your ObservableCollection as you like it, and then it should update. To make the list stay updated, replace the modified item completely.